# ¿porque no se puede enviar los datos de mi formulario?

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de enviar los datos de formulario pero me sale un error que  dice asi index.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: this.submit is not a function
at HTMLFormElement.validarFormulario (index.js:33)
validarFormulario @ index.js:33 he estado buscando para solucionarlo pero he tenidi exito me gustari un poco de ayuda gracias.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener("submit",validarFormulario);
});


function validarFormulario(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    if (nombre.length == 0) {
       mostrarAlerta("Complete su nombre","error");
        return;
    }
    const correo = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (correo == 0) {
       mostrarAlerta("Complete el correo","error");
        return;
    }

    const selector = document.getElementById("seleccion").selectedIndex;
    if (selector == null || selector == 0) {
       mostrarAlerta("Elija una provincia"),"error";
        return
    }

    const telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
    if (telefono > 8) {
       mostrarAlerta("maximo 8 digitos","error");    
        return
    }else if (telefono == 0) {
        console.log("ingrese su numero de telefono","error");
        return
    }
    this.submit();
 // formulario.reset();
  //mensajeExito("enviando","correcto");
}

function mensajeExito(mensaje,correcto = null) {
    const exito = document.createElement("P");
    exito.textContent = mensaje;
    if (exito) {
        exito.classList.add("correcto");
    }
    formulario.appendChild(exito)
    setTimeout(() =>{
        exito.remove();
       },3000);
}


function mostrarAlerta(mensaje,error = null) {
    const alerta = document.createElement("P");
    alerta.textContent = mensaje;

    if (alerta) {
        alerta.classList.add("error");
    }

    formulario.appendChild(alerta);
    setTimeout(() =>{
     alerta.remove();
    },5000);
}
```

el error parace que se encuentra this.submit() , perono se que esta mal en mi codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al agregar el listener al formulario, tu función validarFormulario se ejecuta antes del submit.

Sin embargo, en la primera línea de la función usaste:

```
e.preventDefault
```

> Llamar a preventDefault en cualquier momento durante la ejecución,
> cancela el evento, lo que significa que cualquier acción por defecto
> que deba producirse como resultado de este evento, no ocurrirá.

[Detalle de event.PreventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Es decir, que en ese momento ya cancelaste el submit.

Debes eliminar el this.submit() y sustituir los return en los bloques if por e.preventDefault; es decir, se cancela el submit solamente cuando se detecta (mediante alguno de los if), que alguno de los datos es incorrecto.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho